# Google indexing two URLs for the same page - with and without index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel-4, seo

I am new to the trade of Web development. Currently working on five content based websites of a customer. The sites are designed using Laravel 4 and use a shared hosting with no access to configurations. I am required to remove 'index.php' from all the article pages and make them clean URLs for SEO purpose. I am facing two problems. The problems seem to be similar in nature hence quoting both in same question.

**For Addon domains** - I changed the document root of the domains to the 'public' folder of Laravel. Then added the code below in .htaccess file to make the URLs cleaner without the 'index.php' part

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Though the code works fine if URLs are entered directly to browser's address bar. The problem is that now when I search my site in Google.com using ***site:mysite.com*** it shows some of the pages without the index.php part in the URL while some of the pages with index.php in the URL. The worst thing is that some of the the pages appear twice - once with index.php in URL and second time without index.php

e.g. the search result would contain pages with URLS like this -

```
           www.mysite.com/index.php/article-1-content
           www.mysite.com/article-1-content
```

If I am not wrong this would result in duplicate content. Moreover when I open the article page through the URL having index.php, all the other URLs on that page - like internal links and side bar articles also appear with index.php in their URL. What should I do to completely remove index.php from URLs and google index. Please help.

Sorry for making the question too long but my second problem seems to be of similar nature -

**For primary Domain -** I have added whole of the site code in public_html and then added this piece of code to .htaccess file in public_html to change the document root

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^primarydomain.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.primarydomain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

and also code to remove index.php part in .htaccess file of public folder - (same as that in addon domains ). The problem is that on searching in Google each and every article page appear twice with URLs looking something like this

> www.primarydomain.com/article-1-content
>   www.primarydomain.com/public/index.php/article-1-content

google is indexing the URL with 'public/index.php' part as well. What should I do to completely get rid of these not so clean URLs.

Thanks for tolerating such a long question :) any help would be appreciated.
Regards.

Comment: You should perform a `301` redirect whenever the url matches `index.php`. Eventually, Google will remove all links related to the `index.php` and you will not be penalized for duplicate content.

Comment: Thanks @Ohgodwhy for such a quick response. I'll go through 301 redirects. I have a small doubt regarding 301 redirects. I had read somewhere that too many rewrites and redirects affect the performance of the site. As these sites I am working on will be having thousands of content pages gradually. Will such a redirect be counted as a single redirect or a different redirect for every page. Also once I add the 301 redirect code to .htaccess, do I need the rewrite code that I mentioned in the question or can I remove it.

Comment: I doubt you'll see any major hit in the threshold of this as the `301` redirect is just spawning an `apache forker process` to handle the request and then deliver it to a new page, so the php interpreter is never even run. you would be talking some thousands of 301's with a huge visitor base. you can keep the code that you have above.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for a canonical tag.

As long as the URL loads, the canonical tag will do the rest (ie you can specificy which URL to use).

> https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en